# Display all pages under each other Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to display multiple pages under each other? Like in a one scroll page? I'm new to this and am figuring this out.

I found this on the forum, but it doesn't work or I'm using it wrong:

```
<?php $page_id = 30;  //Page ID
       $page_data = get_page( $page_id );
       //Guardar variáveis
       $title = $page_data->post_title;
       $content = apply_filters('get_the_content', $page_data->post_content);?>
      <div id="box-title">
      <div id="titulo-publicidade">
      <?php echo $title; //Show title ?>
      </div>
     <div id="box-content">
     <?php echo $content; //Show content ?>
```

I hope someone can help me with this. I want the home page to be separate and then the second page to have all the different pages under each other. Like when you scroll you get a different background.

Comment: `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`

Comment: I already have that. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can query `page` in `wordpress` like this

```
<?php
$args = array(
     'posts_per_page' => '6',
     'post_type' => 'page'
  );
$page_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($page_query->have_posts()) : while ($page_query->have_posts()) : $page_query->the_post();
?>
//display content
<?php
     endwhile; endif;
?>
```

if you don't want to display all the `pages` then you can enable `categories` in page and query the pages according to `category` the page is assigned to.

**UPDATE**

This will add category to your page, just add the following to your `functions.php`

```
// Adding Category taxonomy to Page
function add_categories_to_pages() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_categories_to_pages' );
```

Comment: This will help with the one page theme thingy? I can stack them on top of each other?

Comment: this `query` will return all the `page`, so if you want only specific page then you must categorise the pages